# Responsive web design

Tags: rwd

i am working as a inventory controller and IT professional the problem i am facing is before our store website was not responsive and build by someone on freelance but now they want responsive website.
i am messed up where to start.
need help for making that site responsive.

Comment: If you want, you can hire someone or if you want to do it yourself then you need to learn about css3 media queries and html5.

Comment: i want to do it my self so in feature our other webstores i will make that responsive as well.

Comment: try to use bootstrap,

Comment: go through http://www.lingulo.com/tutorials/css/how-to-build-a-html5-website-from-scratch

Comment: do u think boot strap works in  my case

Comment: The question you are asking is too broad and it cannot be answered within the scope of this Q&A website. Please search for a tutorial on this topic (as others are suggesting) and if you encounter more specific issues, feel free to ask them here, providing enough context.

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap, it has a grid system to easily define the differences between a desktop and mobile app.

W3Schools has a great all around tutorial for learning bootstrap, it won't take you long.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Regards.